# Under what conditions are these matrices similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Under what conditions are the matrices $A$ and $A'$ similar?
 $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & a & b \\
  0 & 1 & c \\
  0 & 0 & 2
 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$A'=\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & a' & b' \\
  0 & 1 & c' \\
  0 & 0 & 2
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$m_A(x)=m_{A'}(x)=-(x-1)^2(x-2)$ so I think I should check if the rank of the matrices
 \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & a & b \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix} and \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & a' & b' \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix} are equal (these matrices are $A-I$ and $A'-I$). The ranks are equal when

- $a=a'=0$ or
- $a\neq 0$ and $a'\neq 0$.

Is this a valid solution?

Comment: Why does $m(x) = (x-1)^2 (x-2)$ and not $m(x) = (x-1) (x-2)$?

Comment: Because $(A-I)(A-2I)\neq 0$

Comment: Well, only if $a$ and $a'$ are non null...

Comment: BTW, $A-I=\begin{pmatrix}0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, not $\begin{pmatrix}0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & {\mathbf0}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS True, I actually row-reduced them

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS Why only if $a$ and $a'$ are non null?

Comment: Are these matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @alan : well, there are some matrices $A$ such that $(A-I)(A-2I)$ **is** a minimal cancelling polynomial. But $a=a'=0$ is not sufficient, I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have reached the correct answer (that is, the matrices are similar whenever $a = 0 \iff a' = 0$).  However, your justification follows an incorrect line of reasoning.  Here is a correct justification:

The minimal polynomials depend on the entries.  However, you do know that both *characteristic polynomials* will be $(x-1)^2(x-2)$.  In its Jordan form, each matrix has either a size $2$ Jordan block for $\lambda = 1$, or two size one Jordan blocks for $\lambda = 1$. In order to determine which of these structures occurs, it suffices to check $\operatorname{rank}(A - I),\operatorname{rank}(A' - I)$.  If they're the same, then the two matrices must be similar.